# What is the order of execution for method decorators?

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

Consider the following JavaScript code:

```
class Example {

    @foo
    public methodOne() {}

    @bar
    public methodTwo() {}

}
```

In what order will `foo` and `bar` be executed? Do note that I am not interested in how variou JS engines implement it, but what is the correct way according to the spec. I need to know if I can rely on this behaviour being consistent across JS engines.

It would also be interesting to know if TypeScript decorators behave the same way.

Comment: It should not matter in which order methods are declared, and it should not matter which method is decorated first. What are you trying to do that you think you need to rely on the order of execution?

Comment: Its for a router (as of now not yet written) where you would decorate methods with `@get("index.htm")` to map them to HTTP requests.

Comment: You mean you wouldn't map them to individual files (without duplicates, obviously), but rather to *rules* for which the order they're applied in does matter? TBH, I wouldn't do that using a `class` at all, and not even use methods - their names would be insignificant. It should be a list (array) of rule-function-tuples (objects) instead.

Comment: @Bergi I have reasons for the design that this comment is to narrow to contain. Suffice it to say that I am interested in the answer to this question even if all applications of it are quite stupid.

Comment: Then yes, class elements are evaluated in order of appearance: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In what order will foo and bar be executed?

In order of appearance. So `foo` then `bar`.